# iDRAC 5 that is reporting the wrong host name

Tags: drac

I have a iDRAC 5 that is reporting the wrong host name. I checked DNS to see if that was the issue and it wasn't. Anybody have any thoughts?  Google wasn't much of a friend this time.

Answer (score 1):

If you have set up the host name via the iDRAC configuration utility but this is not the host name you see, check to see if a host name has also been set via OMSA as this can take precedence.

http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/software/smdrac3/idrac/idrac1.0/en/readme/readme.txt